# Why is the asyncio is blocking with the processPool?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a following code:

```
import time
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def blocking_func(x):
    print("In blocking waiting")
    time.sleep(x) # Pretend this is expensive calculations
    print("after blocking waiting")
    return x * 5

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()

    out = yield from loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_func, 2)  # This does not
    print("after process pool")
    print(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
In blocking waiting
after blocking waiting
after process pool
10
```

But I was expecting the process pool will run the code in different process. So I was expecting the output to be:

Expecting output:

```
In blocking waiting
after process pool
after blocking waiting
10
```

I thought if we run the code on process pool it would not block the main loop.But in the output it came back to the main event loop after it is done with the blocking function.

What is blocking the event loop? Is it the blocking_function? If it is the blocking_function what is the use of having the process pool?

Answer (score 2):

`yield from` here means "wait for coroutine to complete and return its result". Comparing to Python threading API, it is like calling `join()`.

To get desired result, use something like this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()

    task = loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_func, 2)
    # at this point your blocking func is already running
    # in the executor process

    print("after process pool")

    out = yield from task

    print(out)
```

Comment: Does the process pool means we have multiple process in which we can run the code in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines arent' t separate processes. The difference is that coroutines need to give up control to the loop by themselves. This means if you have a blocking coroutine then it will block the whole loop.

The reason you use coroutines is mainly to handle I/O activities. If you are waiting for a message you can simply check a socket and if nothing happens you will return to the main loop. Then other coroutines can be handled before finally the control comes back to the IO function.

In your case it makes sense to use `await asyncio.sleep(x)` instead of `time.sleep(x)`. This way control is suspended from `blocking_func()` for the sleep time. Afterwards control goes back there and the result should be  as you expected it.

More infos: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: Is the process pool will have multiple process in it which can be executed in parallel?

Comment: @aja Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: ProcessPoolExecutor() will it executes the code on a single process or will there be multiple processes whcih will execute the code in parallel ?

Comment: ProcesPoolExecutor uses multiple processes. In fact you can specify how many workers should be used. Have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

Comment: So I can run two different piece of code in parallel? If yes I want to run the blocking code in separate process which will not block the main process. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.

Comment: If that is the case `out = yield from loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_func, 2)  # This does not
    print("after process pool")`   after we yield the the next print should be printed without waiting for the blocking call ?

Comment: doing `yield from loop.run_in_executor()` is useless. You create child process, and then tell parent process to wait for child process result. So you are effectively blocking parent process

Comment: it is `loop.run_in_executor()` call that is launching your blocking code in parallel, not `yield from` expression. This call returns object of class `Future` which represents a value which will be available eventually.

After you have a reference to Future object, you can do whatever you want in main process, and it will be non blocking. When you eventually will need a value from blocking func, you call `yield from future` - this blocks until value is available

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky A minor nit: `await loop.run_in_executor(...)` is not necessarily useless. While it does block the current coroutine, it does not block the whole parent process; it still allows _other_ coroutines to run. Blocking a coroutine with `await` is a feature when the coroutine needs the result from the process pool to continue its work. It *is* useless in the context of the OP's desire of running several such calls in parallel, all from the same coroutine.

Comment: yeah, I meant exclusively OP's situation, but my statement seems to be too strong, thanks